# Change the HTML attribute location in runtime

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to move html element on run time.

(1) Call function from code behind. (Button1_Click1 event)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "myfunction", "testFunc(100,200);", true);
```

(2) It redirect to JS function. (This function is used to change the location of html attribute)

```
 function testFunc(x,y) {
    document.getElementById('draggable').style.top = x;
    document.getElementById('draggable').style.left = y;
    }
```

in number 2, if add alert, it's working properly. (It means function is executing successfully)

But html div is not changing. What could be the problem?

This is my HTML code.

```
 <div>
    <b>This is test page<br />
    </b>
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-icon-image">
    <img id="img1" src="/Resource/location_icon.png" width="27px" height="45px" />
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click1" />
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean your server code is returning javascript??? and why are you even calling the server just to move an html element??

Comment: My requirement is getting X & Y value from the DB and set location of the image on run time. That's why I call to a JS function from code behind. Or will you please tell me is there any other way to fulfill my requirement?